# Is it OK to retrieve cellular location when location setting is OFF?

Tags: android, locationmanager, telephonymanager, cellular-network

On Android, we can retrieve CellLocation using [this API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCellLocation%28%29)

This API requires location(Coarse or Fine) permission to be granted.

We observed that API returns valid CellLocation even if global location-setting is OFF.  Ideally, it should not give cell-location when location-setting is OFF.

Is the current API behavior intentional? Is it a bug in Android? Is it OK to access CellularLocation even if location setting is OFF?

Comment: what do you mean by `global location settings`? do you mean the GPS toggle on the notification bar quick settings panel?

Comment: Yes I mean the Location setting. We can turn it on/off from notification or from Location Settings. If this setting is off then we can not retrieve Geo-location (Latitude, Longitude)........ Do you think same should be the case for Cellular info as well?

Comment: no, i think that toggle should control the GPS component only, you are still allowed to get location as permitted by the APIs

Comment: We can enable/disable location from Location settings (Settings App -> Location).. If Android allows to get Cell Location even if this setting is OFF then why does it ask to get the location permission?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate systems here:

1. App permissions
2. User toggles

If an app received the `Location` permission, it's allowed to use the API to get location whenever and however is wants (you should obviously take battery and data usage in consideration, but that's up to you).

If a certain settings toggle is switched on or off by the user, it's **up to the API** to turn off certain features from apps, it's not the app's responsibility to check system settings whenever it wants to use an API.

In your case the location setting can be toggled by the user to prevent usage of the GPS component to prevent accurate location tracking and to save battery.
This does not apply to cell-tower location as it's definitely not accurate and the data already exists on the phone so no battery power is needed either.
Android may in the future turn off cell-tower location when this setting is off, but until then you're **allowed** to use whatever the API gives you.

Comment: This Location Setting toggle is not only related to GPS. There are 3 modes of Location Settings. Out of these, "Battery Saving Mode" is not related to GPS. If this location setting is OFF then we can NOT retrieve coarse location (from mobile and wifi networks) as well... So, I doubt if we should consider this Location Setting as only related to GPS.. Hence, this worries me if it is correct to retrieve Cell info when this location setting is OFF.